# Using AWS-Amplify -> "amplify push" not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

To understand how to use AWS-Amplify I am following [this document](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?platform=purejs).

It all goes well, except when reaching this command:

```
$ amplify push
```

It ends like this:

```
Following resources failed

Resource Name: PinpointFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Event Type: create
Reason: The runtime parameter of nodejs6.10 is no longer supported 
for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use 
the new runtime (nodejs8.10) while creating or updating functions. 
(Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: xxxx-8a8e-.....-yyyy-zzzz)

✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
```

Why am I getting this error? I have already run the same command in the past. And I did not change my NodeJS version.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/node-js-6-is-approaching-end-of-life-upgrade-your-aws-lambda-functions-to-the-node-js-10-lts/

Comment: The error explicitly states - _The runtime parameter of nodejs6.10 is **no longer** supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions._

Comment: Indeed, but it was still supported until quite recently then. Anyway I also saw this part of the message an tried to fix it but did not find the way to change this nodejs6.10 to nodejs8.10 as requested. I may have looked at the wrong info. I actually had a look at the doc you mention, but it did not seem to give me a solution on how to change (only comments about the difference).

Comment: Try to find the text **nodejs6.10** in your project, it should probably be in a .yaml file somewhere

Comment: OK. I am doing that now using the find command.

Comment: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/lambda-node-version-update

Comment: OK. In the mean while I found a file. I will also look at your URL.

Comment: Did you run `amplify configure` before?

Answer (score 2):

All references to node 6.10 should have been updated to 8.10 in the Amplify CLI.  Most of the references you will be looking for in your current configuration should be in the cloudformation files, which are either json or yml.   You can change those references manually and push, and if you have the latest version of the CLI installed it shouldn't be a problem going forward.